# Creating folders with names that includes non-ASCII characters

Tags: php, windows

i am creating folders from PHP with non-ASCII characters in their names. e.g ¡Mucho gusto!, Adiós, Buenos días.

I'm using the `mkdir()` function. When my script executes the folder created on my drive is a mess. `¡Mucho gusto!` becomes `Â¡Mucho gusto!` with similar problems for other names. The HTML document containing the PHP script has its charset set to utf-8, but Windows corrupts the folder name. When i tested it on my server, the folder name was correct but locally there is sumthing wrong with the Windows setting. I am using Windows XP SP3.

Comment: This sounds potentially very painful. I don't know what the specific problem you're running into is, but as you mention, it's probably something to do with the encodings.

Comment: As far as I remember, XP does not allow `!` in folder names?!

Comment: yea but the confusing point is why does my web server creates the rite folder and my local server doesnot!! i guess may be i need to tell my windows to create folder in utf-8 :S

Comment: Good old windows... Try changing encodings as suggested.

Comment: @powtac: copy ¡Mucho gusto! and create a folder by this name :)

Comment: @ David & mkram: how do u change encoding? i mean my page from where the php script resides, is set to utf-8! do i need to do another encoding?

Comment: Add `trim()` to your folder name the `Â` seems to be a whitespace problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

got it!! i need to utf8_decode() my path before making the mkdir() call cauze the windows xp expects and deliver the folder name in ISO-8859-1.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you to encode the folder names with [**Punycode**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punycode). Since all common OS have restrictions for folder names.

There is a [online demo for Punycode here](http://www.charset.org/punycode.php). And also a [PHP class is available for the automatic translation](http://phlymail.com/en/downloads/idna/download/).

Comment: Thanks alot powtac..so when i do mkdir($path,0777), the path shud be in punny code?

Comment: No, you have to call the class with the name of the folder first!